# Android Application working correctly on Nexus 7 but not on Nexus 4

Tags: android, android-fragments, nexus-7, nexus-4

I'm new to android app development and i'm following a tutorial on fragments, the final application is working correctly on Nexus 7 but not on Nexus 4. Both have android 4.4.2 installed. 
Here is a zip file of android project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108022472/fragments.zip
I'm getting the following error with Nexus 4.

```
12-31 11:48:29.592  21384-21384/com.example.fragment2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fragment2, PID: 21384
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragment2/com.example.fragment2.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030002
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030002
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2309)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:939)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.example.fragment2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone explains why the error is happening with Nexus 4 and not Nexus 7

Comment: Its a resource error. check your res folder, for `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030002`

Comment: as nexus -7 and nexus 4 have different screen size so there are different layout and values folder for respective device.

Comment: But I do have two different layouts, for small screen & big screen

Comment: @Noor: follow my answer..

Comment: If u keep on practicing you will come to know designing for multiple devices. For now follow my simple answer.

Comment: @Noor for nexus 4 and nexus 7 you should check your resources. the ID of all resources should be same for all layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it plainly: the system can't find resource with id `#0x7f030002`, available for Nexus 4.

To solve this, go to your R class, and look for the name of that resource; I see this is the id of `news_articles` layout. Now, a simple check in you `layout` folder will show you that you don't have any file with that name there, but only in the `layout-large` one.

So, create a `news_articles` layout in the `layout` folder, to be used by all screen sizes; or, if it's not needed for regular phones, use reflection in code, in your java class, to make sure it's not asked for.

Comment: U r right, news_articles was not there, instead, it was written as new_articles without an 's' :/

Comment: Indeed, it can happen, but to avoid this, I usually copy the first layout xml into a specific folder, and edit it there, to be sure I preserve all the ids.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragment2/com.example.fragment2.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030002
```

Android engine is unable to find resources which is suitable for Nexus 4. So check your res folder.  For temporary result You can do following thing. create drawable, layout folders in res folder. Then copy your layouts, drawables to respective folders. Then You will come out of this error easily